# How to balance or restrict magical teleportation so that my characters have to travel by foot?

Tags: balancing-magic-systems, teleportation

My universe have these rules applied to teleportation:

- Any individual can learn the teleportation magic. Though it takes a lot of "mana" normally out of reach by one person, so they either use special mana batteries to open a portal or work together. My main characters are of a race ("A") which have enough mana to open a portal easily by one person.
- The cities make a restrictive barriers to prevent random teleportations for safety. They build static teleportation stations, where you shedule and pay for your teleport. Some people have "keys" to city barriers and can teleport freely, or one can use a huge amount of "mana" to break through a barrier.
- The larger the teleported mass and farther the destination, the more mana it costs, but it is relatively easy in terms of mana to open a portal anywhere on a planet. An other planet in the system will take too much mana to reach, and needs a really huge mana battery.
- You don't need to visit a place before opening a portal, you just need coordinates of the place, which can be counted approximately, and then made more precise by opening a small portal and adjusting it better. It is common to carry with them lists of destination points for the "A" race, since they teleport easily.

Now I want my characters of "A" race to travel by foot. Many lands are either wild or ruins with no infrastructure. It would be logical to just jump to the destination instead of walking AND they have a group of mages who can build a portal for them. What can I do to restrict that kind of teleportation? Or what can be a reason for someone to travel by foot?

Comment: It's your magic system you can choose to balance it however you want. What makes you think that this question has a singular answer? Remember that we're not a brainstorming site and that we're not here to generate ideas of build your world for you.

Comment: A focused question about a worldbuilding item is on-topic, even if it's magic. Also, even a site moderator answered this one. Question should not have been closed. Voted to reopen.

Comment: This question is essentially asking for brainstorming. The question is also to vague.  What teleport distance is trying to avoided? somebody teleporting around their house? the next city? across the continent?   Only cost given is mana no mention of how fast mana cost rises, no mention of cast time, or components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Fat Princess

[image]

*Image from the video game Fat Princess*

There is an enemy army between our heroes and the capital of Athenium. They can of course teleport past the army any time they want. But then who will save the princess?

You see the reason they are going to Athenium is to bring the Bastard Princess Mardge to reclaim her throne. The royal family have all perished for some exciting and plot relevant reason.

The party mage (that's him on the bottom left) can teleport himself no problemo. But Mardge is a hefty gal. The bigger the load the more mana to teleport it. Our Master Wizard's mana bar is simply too small to teleport both himself and Mardge. So they are forced to go the long way by foot.

This leads to all sorts of party-based shenanigans and adventure. As the journey progresses the mage gets a bigger mana bar. Not only that, but Mardge sheds some excess lard from all the running and jumping around. Imagine their surprise when they finally reach the capital and realise they can now easily teleport right back to where they started.

If a big fat princess is not to your liking, simply replace her with any large object that cannot be split apart and teleported in several trips.

A chest full of gold coins doesn't work. Master Wizard can zip back and forth every day with a handful of coins.

A single 100kg diamond works. If you break it you bought it.

Perhaps the large object is a Mysterious Chest which they must protect and deliver. But they are not allowed look inside the chest. That is what makes it mysterious

Comment: Upvote for Mardge’s mysterious chest!  UPvote!  Although it is not actually that mysterious.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great way to solve my problem! An Unteleportable Object Transportation, for any reason it is unteleportable.

Answer (score 6):

You have your reason already:

> it takes a lot of "mana" normally out of reach by one person

Look at our world. Airplanes are a convenient means of transportation, but nobody uses an airplane to go buy bread at the grocery down the road, because it costs too much with respect to the outcome. Most people would simply walk there.

Make the cost of the mana (or of its batteries) high enough, and most people will have a sufficient incentive to walk.

It happened already in the past: for those who cannot afford a horse or a donkey, feet were the only means of transportation.

Comment: I feel the airplane is a really good analogy. For the vast majority of people, the only way to fly is in group. Which will then translate to probably having a "group teleportation" service that will somewhat mimic airplane travel. Yet, if you cannot put many people through the portal at once, then the costs might still be prohibitive for most people.

Comment: As I said in my post, my characrters have a good amount of mana, enough to make that teleportation easy for them. The cost of teleportation makes trading routes by sea or roads more efficient, but teleporting a few people would be cheap enough to make it an easier way as things are now

Answer (score 4):

**Teleporting gives away your location.**

Teleporting is much like a plane.  It is hard to hide a plane.  There are people who are watching the relevant area for disturbances.  If someone teleports in, the watchers can be right there a split second later, with many questions and ways to get answers.

The watchers are only watching for teleportation.  Because who would walk? So if you want to be sneaky you gotta schlep it on foot.

Comment: This is great way, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Prohibitvely large, non-mobile, non-teleporting infrastructure is necessary for long-distance teleportation**

Large machines with large mana batteries which generate portals but cannot go through portals themselves without even larger machines making even larger portals, portal gates, are necessary to calculate and constantly readjust your teleport's point B if you cannot directly observe your destination, as you aren't simply teleporting from Hassleworth to Portmouth, you're teleporting from where Hassleworth is right now to where Portmouth would be once you step outside of the portal in a second or two, which on the scale of the moving parts of the solar system or even the galaxy could be so far off your intended mark that you've basically teleported into open space. So these machines are basically a necessity to make sure you don't turn into a soon to be dead astronaut.

Short distance teleportation like blink or whatever you call your combat-ready teleportation spell still works fine as you don't need a large machine to calculate where you're going as you can already see your destination, but cannot be used to circumvent the issue of long-distance teleportation with cameras or scrying orbs or whatever as there is a slight bit of lag between what happens where you are viewing and what you are seeing in the orb, further compounding the problem of accidentally teleporting into space.

Answer (score 1):

**Quarantine, magnet for enemies and conservation of momentum**

Assuming that when a portal is opened then it allows travel in either direction, then anything from airborne viruses to fungal spores to hostile monsters with tentacles and/or claws can come through the other way.  Given that this is a world with magic, this increases the variety of unwanted things that may breach quarantine by coming through in the opposite direction.  This is an even greater risk if the cause of the destination's wild and/or ruined state is due to "bad things".  (Note that a world with widespread teleportation is a nightmare scenario for pandemics and uncontrolled spread of small pests.)

Secondly, opening a portal may be like setting off a flare that attracts "bad things" to the immediate vicinity.  It's fine to open a portal to another city - a city will keep its pests under control and will not have any free-roaming tigers/hornets/magic-sucking mosquitoes that home in on a newly opened portal.  The wilderness is a very different story.  Along similar lines, it may be that the protagonists have sapient enemies who can detect portals being opened much more easily than people using their legs for transport - it's a staple of fantasy books that the powerful magic users cannot solve all problems with their magic because excessive use will let the bad guys track them.

Finally, the perennial problem with long-range teleport abilities that many writers ignore is conservation of momentum.  Assuming that the world obeys normal physical laws other than permitting the use of magic, any two widely separated points on the surface will have very different vectors.  Moving an item from point A to point B is likely to result in it flying off towards the horizon unless this is compensated for somehow.  Cities may have a designated terminal that allow (insert technobabble explanation) momentum of arriving people and objects to be zeroed, the wilderness may not.  (In addition to stopping the arrival of invading armies and smugglers, preventing the unexpected arrival of fast-moving objects that can rearrange the architecture due to their energies is another good reason for cities to have restrictive anti-teleport barriers.)  Wilderness destinations will not have these facilities, meaning that arrivals are likely to embed themselves in trees, cliffs or other terrain features.

Finally, there are a multitude of plot reasons why teleporting may be a bad idea.  It could be that key observations need to be made by "walking the ground".  If enemies are operating in the area then the risk of teleporting into the middle of their camp could be significant.  If the ruins are trapped or otherwise hazardous then opening a portal and stepping through to fall into a spiked pit might be considered unwise.

Answer (score 1):

> Hmm, I would call it good manners. Before entering, one must first let out those who wish to depart. Do you know how many creatures there are on various planes that crave the opportunity to use random gaps to escape to other worlds?

*You don't want to let them out...*

One possibility is that the process of creating a portal elsewhere allows beings from other planes of existence to enter your world by creating a portal in another plane/universe/dimension. Alternatively, the process of going through a created portal involves briefly traversing that other dimension. Whatever the case may be, creating a portal out of the blue leaves the user open to attack by extradimensional beings. Best case scenario is that they'll ignore the user and go run around the world. Second-best case scenario is that whatever is released into this world will simply rip apart the caster. Otherwise, the mortal foolish enough to have opened a portal outside of a warded location may very well find his body colonized by parasites made of suffering and misery while his perception of time is altered to such a degree that what looks like one second to an outside observer feels like years to our hapless victim (So that his newfound "friends" can better feast on mortal suffering in the short time before his rather gruesome demise, of course).

Part of the process of establishing the pay-to-portal zones you've described is setting up magical wards and barriers to prevent extradimensional "guests" from  invading the world and preying on whoever is unlucky (or stupid) enough to be nearby when it happens. Doing so requires significantly more mana than even a person of 'A' can procure and requires maintenance. Your party simply doesn't have the oomph to do it without a good chance of suffering a fate worse than death.

Answer (score 1):

Every act of teleportation attracts negative energy that makes you unlucky. Greater distance between points of teleportation brings greater negative energy. Greater total mass that traveled through portal bring greater negative energy to the creator of said portal. By abusing teleportation you become a walking disaster, danger to yourself and anybody around you.

Answer (score 1):

Mechanically, the main thing to watch out for is what happens to objects when you teleport into the same space as them?  It could be that the spell takes this into account, but that was something not brought up that could be a factor.

Aside from that, there isn't really a mechanical reason why it is and others have already brought up the other mechanical and potentially mechanical reasons for such a thing.  So I'll bring up the other side to Race A:

### Culture:  For More Than Just Yogourt

Efficiency wise, it does make sense for your people to teleport where they need to so long as it saves them time and/or energy to do so.  This answer isn't about efficiency.

What this is about is how Race A are as a people and how they interact with the world.  They probably can teleport themselves from bed to work and home again, but as a people and in general, would they do that?

#### Teleport Etiquette

Depending on how your people are and how this teleportation developed, there may be whole culture involving the act of teleporting.  A set of societal norms that your people follow because it keeps things working.

Of course they will realize or be taught they they **can** teleport to certain places, but also that they **shouldn't** do that.  Those unwritten rules, or even codified laws in some places, could have things like:

- No teleporting into our out of places of businesses.  It will be presumed that you are up to no good.
- It is customary not to teleport directly inside a personal residence for privacy reasons.
- It is customary to warn or plan your teleports to prevent untimely accidents

Overall, the premise is that there is an entire etiquette surrounding the skill, that that does not go into places where the skill has been disabled, such as within cities as stated in the question.

#### Travel Plans

Something to point out is that unless your Race A folks maintain the destination coordinate points almost religiously so that they will always be functional, a set of destination coordinates that were useful when it was written might not be good in a year or five.  As such, unless one has a fresher list of destinations, it is actually safer to walk.

Alternatively, the travel may be the point.  Travelling between cities by foot means that one can inspect the roadways to see if they are safe or not.  Also, it verifies the coordinates that you carry as well as potentially finding little off-path campsites that you can make note of to teleport to later.  Those little hidey-holes of nature you'd never find if you just teleported everywhere.

Indeed, there may be a sect of ranger-types in your Race A who are tasked to protect the roadways because it both verifies the teleport points to make sure that they are still valid ones and they are easily able to escape from sticky situations by warping home in a panic if need be.

Likewise if this is a skill you learn as you grow up, a child might not able to teleport as far as a parent, if at all.  For those times, it is better to travel by foot or cart than to risk teleporting with a screaming child in your hands.  Not only will the constant movement be a distraction, but it's harder to take another person with you, even if they share blood.

Answer (score 0):

Teleporting uses up most of your mana. If a monster leaps out on you when you have full mana, you can easily fight it off. If you have spent most of your mana on a teleport, and then a monster attacks, your dead.
So for safety, you walk out into the wilderness, and teleport back.